# How to display events text in codeigniter calendar?

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I am using Codeigniter 3.0 Calendar Library, I am not getting event text in my CI calendar, Instead of displaying event text it shows link on the number.

Sample Codeigniter Code:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->display($year = null, $month = null);
    }
     public function display($year = null, $month = null)
    {
            $config = array(
            'show_next_prev' => TRUE,
            'show_other_days' => TRUE,
            'next_prev_url' => site_url('welcome/display')
            );
            $events = array(
                1 =>'test1',
                2 =>'test2'
            );
            $this->load->library('calendar', $config);
            echo $data['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $events);

    }
}
```

Sample Calendar image (output of above code) :

[image]

In the above calender you can see 1st and 2nd days are linked and not displaying events text like `test1` and `test2` in the calendar, how can i rectify this?

Comment: According to CI docs `text1` and `text2` is needs to be `url` you need to provide for that event. So what you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to print event name in cells. @IndrasinhBihola

Comment: What if there is more than one event on specified day??

Comment: That may be my next issue, for now i have to display an event for each day, else i will display number of events in the cells. (tell me how to add multi or single events)

Comment: Why don't you try some jquery plugin? That might be better option for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify any piece of calendar template, change content and just provide data. For example you can provide title attribute inside a element, to use it as simple tooltip on hover, or adjust html to provide more sophisticated ui interaction. Take a look:

```
$prefs['template'] = array(
        'cal_cell_content'       => '{content}',
        'cal_cell_content_today' => '<div class="highlight">{content}</div>'
    );
    $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
    $data = array(
        3  => '<a title="my event" href="http://example.com/news/article/2006/03/">My event</a>',
        7  => '<a title="conference" href="http://example.com/news/article/2006/07/">Conference</a>',
        13 => '<a title="lecture" href="http://example.com/news/article/2006/13/">Lecture</a>',
        26 => '<a title="city walk" href="http://example.com/news/article/2006/26/">City walk</a>'
    );


    echo $this->calendar->generate(2015, 6, $data);
```